# Grails, Grails RabbitMQ plugin, Java ,Spring AMQP - Multiple clients

Tags: java, grails, rabbitmq, grails-plugin, spring-amqp

I have developed simple Grails REST web service that uses Grails RabbitMQ plugin and sends message to queue.

**Grails - Config.groovy**

```
queues = {
    exchange name: 'my.topic', type: topic, durable: false, {
        foo durable: true, binding: 'test.#'

    }
}
```

On my Java Desktop App I try to listen to that message using *Spring AMQP*

**Main.java**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CachingConnectionFactory cf = new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
     cf.setUsername("guest");
     cf.setPassword("guest");
        RabbitAdmin admin = new RabbitAdmin(cf);
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container =
                new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(cf);

        Object listener = new Object() {
            public void handleMessage(String foo) {
                System.out.println(foo);
            }
        };

        MessageListenerAdapter adapter = new MessageListenerAdapter(listener);
        container.setMessageListener(adapter);
        container.setQueueNames("foo");
        container.start();
}
```

When I run multiple clients (say two) sometimes one recive "message" , sometimes another.
How can both clients recive "message" on every "send" (I send messsage from my index Grails controller by reloading page).

What is prefered way to do this ? I am newbie :)

Answer (score 2):

Each consumer needs its own queue bound to the exchange.

Multiple consumers on the same queue compete for messages.

Comment: Is it posible to develop one application that will listen for different messages on that queue's. How will my Main.java, look then ?

Comment: No. Unlike JMS, there is no concept of message selectors on a queue in AMQP. You have to configure the exchange to do the selection in the broker. You can listen to multiple queues in one listener container but you can't listen for only selected messages (if that's what you mean).

Comment: How can I listen to multiple queues in one listener . Can you show me some code please. I am trying to learn AMQP concept its hard.

Comment: container.setQueueNames("foo", "bar", "baz"); I suggest you look at the [Spring AMQP sample apps](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.3.7.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/sample-apps.html) to get started. Also see the [RabbitMQ Tutorials](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-java.html).

Comment: Thank you. Can this concept, AMQP with RabbitMQ be used for next scenario. Creating java desktop application, where will multiple instances of same app run od different machines on private network.  How will all apps detect changes from server (sending message from Grails server) Can you give me basic concept description of that in short.